# Реализовать разбор двоичного формата данных

Tags: python

Реализовать разбор двоичного формата данных. Данные начинаются с сигнатуры 0x4b 0x49 0x50 0x5d, за которой следует структура A. Порядок байт: от младшего к старшему. Адреса указаны в виде смещений от начала данных. В решении предлагается использовать модуль struct.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример 1

Двоичные данные:

(b'KIP]X\x00\xf1\x11&\xe1\xb3\xd8o\xb1>\x02\x00s\x00\x00\x00\xd8=\xfbW\x81\xcdy'
b'\xe1\xccu>\x03X\xcf\xcbPU\xee:\x18\x8a!\x14\xc8\xee\xed#C^\xf0\xa2"7\xf8`'
b'\xa7\xe17cD\r2\xc9\x82\xa0\xdfU\x9f\x93\xc0\x8b2\xff\xe2\x88& \x82\x8f'
b'\xe7?\x1e#Q|\xede\xb4\xf6M\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x02Y\x19\xbf\x05\x00S'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x02r\xeb\x1c\xba\x87\xe2\xbf\x1b\x08\x9e>g\x82\t?')

Результат разбора:

{'A1': {'B1': -2380,
'B2': 77,
'B3': [{'C1': -3506048743108714119,
'C2': [203, 80],
'C3': -4029558889594032555,
'C4': 2495821431160696302,
'C5': 63543},
{'C1': 3606614069523621728,
'C2': [201, 130],
'C3': 3642216463925108640,
'C4': 16685698219028046591,
'C5': 7743}],
'B4': -0.599014401435852,
'B5': [35, 81, 124, -19, 101],
'B6': -0.5790682377660803},
'A2': {'D1': 3777368561,
'D2': -1318070093,
'D3': 62,
'D4': [0.30865558981895447, 0.5371460318565369],
'D5': 15832},
'A3': -5,
'A4': 87,
'A5': 129,
'A6': -51}

```
class Types:
    int8 = 'b'
    int16 = 'h'
    int32 = 'i'
    int64 = 'q'
    uint8 = 'B'
    uint16 = 'H'
    uint32 = 'I'
    uint64 = 'Q'
    float = 'f'
    double = 'd'
    char = 's'


class BinaryReader:
    def __init__(self, data, offset, order='<'):
        self.data = data
        self.offset = offset
        self.order = order

    def jump_to(self, offset):
        reader = BinaryReader(self.data, offset, self.order)
        return reader

    def read(self, frmt):
        data = unpack_from(self.order + frmt, self.data, self.offset)
        self.offset += calcsize(frmt)
        return data[0]


def read_d(reader):
    d1 = reader.read(Types.uint32)
    d2 = reader.read(Types.int32)
    d3 = reader.read(Types.uint8)
    d4_size = reader.read(Types.uint16)
    d4_offset = reader.read(Types.uint32)
    d4_reader = reader.jump_to(d4_offset)
    d4 = b''.join([d4_reader.read(Types.float)
                   for _ in range(d4_size)]).decode()
    d5 = reader.read(Types.int16)
    return dict(D1=d1, D2=d2, D3=d3, D4=d4, D5=d5)


def read_c(reader):
    c1 = reader.read(Types.int64)
    c2 = [reader.read(Types.uint8) for _ in range(2)]
    c3 = reader.read(Types.int64)
    c4 = reader.read(Types.uint64)
    c5 = reader.read(Types.uint16)
    return dict(C1=c1, C2=c2, C3=c3, C4=c4, C5=c5)


def read_b(reader):
    b1 = reader.read(Types.int16)
    b2 = reader.read(Types.uint8)
    b3_size = reader.read(Types.uint32)
    b3_offset = reader.read(Types.uint16)
    b3_reader = reader.jump_to(b3_offset)
    b3 = [read_c(b3_reader) for _ in range(b3_size)]
    b4 = reader.read(Types.float)
    b5_size = reader.read(Types.uint16)
    b5_offset = reader.read(Types.uint32)
    b5_reader = reader.jump_to(b5_offset)
    b5 = [b5_reader.read(Types.uint8) for _ in range(b5_size)]
    b6 = reader.read(Types.double)
    return dict(B1=b1, B2=b2, B3=b3, B4=b4, B5=b5, B6=b6)


def read_a(reader):
    b_offset = reader.read(Types.uint16)
    b_reader = reader.jump_to(b_offset)
    a1 = read_c(b_reader)
    a2 = read_d(reader)
    a3 = reader.read(Types.int8)
    a4 = reader.read(Types.uint8)
    a5 = reader.read(Types.uint8)
    a6 = reader.read(Types.int8)
    return dict(A1=a1, A2=a2, A3=a3, A4=a4, A5=a5, A6=a6)


def main(data):
    return read_a(BinaryReader(data, 4))
```

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/program.py", line 25, in <module>
    result = main(*args)
  File "<string>", line 85, in main
  File "<string>", line 76, in read_a
  File "<string>", line 41, in read_d
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, float found ```
В чем ошибка?
````

Comment: В строке `d4 = b''.join([d4_reader.read(Types.float)` вы пытаетесь объединить список чисел в байтовую строку — это выглядит как бред, на что собственно и ругается питон

Comment: Спасибо, решил!